# Compare two text files and print the difference against key in bash shell script

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

Shell script, bash, have 2 large files around 1.2 GB data, with key and values, I need to compare both files based on the key and store difference in the value in the third file,
File 2 will always be a subset of File 1, just need to find values(against key) which are not present in file 2 and unique ones in File 1.

File 1:

```
test1 marco;polo;angus
test2 mike;zen;liza
test3 tom;harry;alan
test4 bob;june;janet
1332239_44557576_CONTI Lased & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_no-rule 343323H;343434311H;454656556H;343343432H
1332240_44557576_CONTI Mazed & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_some-rule 232324L;2226556H;343223432H
```

File 2:

```
test1 polo;angus
test2 mike
test4 bob;janet
1332240_44557576_CONTI Mazed & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_some-rule 232324L;343223432H
```

I would like to compare the first two columns of file1 with file2 (search through the entire contents of file2 in first two columns) if they match print the difference of values. Then search for the second line of file 1 and so on. Also keys unique in file 1 should be printed.

Expected Output:

```
test1 marco
test2 zen;liza
test3 tom;harry;alan
test4 june
1332239_44557576_CONTI Lased & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_no-rule 343323H;343434311H;454656556H;343343432H
1332240_44557576_CONTI Mazed & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_some-rule 2226556H
```

The files I have are huge, containing about 100,000 lines, so I would like to make the execution fast. This is running in shell script, using bash shell scripting. These files `file1` and `file2` are text file, with this as key (`1332239_44557576_CONTI Lased & Micro kjd $353.50_30062020_lsdf3_no-rule`) and these as values: (`343323H;343434311H;454656556H;343343432H`)

Comment: 1.2 GB? That why databases are used for such operations.

Comment: cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/q/61298408/1745001. Please don't do that,

Answer (score 1):

If you are committed to shell scripting:  Start by normalizing the files, to key and one value per line.  Then, provided they are sorted, the command `comm` can extract the lines that are in one and not the other.  Then it is just a matter of denormalizing the file again (if you need it).

The better options is probably to build a small program in a more advanced language (I would probably use perl5 myself) to read both input files line by line, and output the differences.  Again, you would want the input sorted, unless you plan to use a LOT of memory.

Presumably you already have programs designed to deal with this format.  Using that software's input functions is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you please let me know how to normalize it !

Comment: Like printing, 
test1 marco
test1 polo and so on..

Comment: right. You can do it with sed by: `sed -e ':1;s/^\([^ ]*\) \([^;]*\);/\1 \2\n\1 /;t1'`

Comment: I was using the term normalize as one of several steps in improving a database schema.  In a database (which, as @FedonKadifeli pointed out in a comment, may be the way to go), One does not, by preference, repeat data within a line, or make the data need to be parsed before local use.  There is something known as "fifth normal form", though in this case, it is first normal form that needs to be applied.